# Haskell building simple JSON parser

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, bytestring

Getting my feet wet with building stuff, and not being able to get Aeson to work properly I decided my new project is building a JSON parser. Very abstract since it is one way or another, so it wouldn't make sense to put all the code here. 
The ByteString library lets me do what I need. Remove characters, replace stuff, but: I have a very hard time reconstructing it the exact way I took it apart. Data.Text however seems more appropriate for the job but when generated a lot of noise with /"/, \n etc.
What would be the best and fastest way to clear a file from all rubbish and restore the remaining parts to useful text? Very small part below. Remarks on the code are welcome. Learning here.

```
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Char
import Data.Text.Encoding as DTE

word8QuoteMark = fromIntegral (ord '"')
word8Newline = fromIntegral (ord '\n')
word8Backslash = fromIntegral (ord ':')

filterJson jsonData = B.filter (/= word8Backslash)
                        (B.filter (/= word8Newline)
                           (B.filter (/= word8QuoteMark) jsonData))

importJson :: IO ()
importJson = do
        jsonData <- B.readFile "local.json"
        output <- return (filterJson jsonData)
        print $ (output)
```

Now the downside is, that if someone is called eg. François, it is now returned as `Fran\195\167ois`. I think I would need a lot more steps to do this in `Data.Text`, but correct me if I am wrong...

Note: i saw in a post that Daniel Wagner strongly advises against `ByteString` for text, but just for the sake of argument.

Comment: The data you read from the file hasn't been decoded yet; do that before attempting to parse it. That "noise" is just how the Unicode text is rendered, not something that actually exists in the data.

Comment: Can I also encode it afterwards?

Comment: @Chepner: your comment qualified as an answer to me by the way, but I don't think I can mark comments as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is, by definition, a Unicode string that represents a data structure. What you get from `B.readFile`, though, is a raw byte string that you must first decode to get a Unicode string. To do that, you need to know what encoding was used to create the file. Assuming the file uses UTF-8 encoding, you can do something like

```
import Data.Text

importJson :: String -> IO Text
importJson name = do
    jsonData <- B.readFile name
    return (Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8 jsonData)
```

Once you have a `Text` value, you can parse that into some data structure according to the JSON grammar.

Comment: Thanks for that. So it is not the most charming way to parse JSON I came up with, still ending up with Data.Text as Daniel Wagner posted in another question.